# Core Plot - How to display axis labels under plot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm working with a CorePlot scatter plot, and I'm having trouble putting the finishing touches on the axis label styling. I'd like for the plot to overlap above the Y-axis labels, but the opposite is happening. I've scoured the documentation, but can't find any options to do this.

Here's the output:

[image: Graph output]

I've tried manipulating the ZPosition of both the plot & axis labels, but that doesn't seem to be working:

```
[plot setZPosition:99];
[axisSet.yAxis.axisLabels each:^(CPTAxisLabel *label) {
    [label.contentLayer setZPosition:-1];
}];
```

*Note - [Objective Sugar](https://github.com/mneorr/ObjectiveSugar) used for loop comprehension*

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot area has a property called [topDownLayerOrder](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_plot_area.html#a6aecfbc326c5fecbd6e60f476736b9e9) that allows you to rearrange the different graph elements in exactly this way.